# Need help creating a new case record type and page layout for internal SFDC support requests

Tags: case, page-layout, support

I'm preparing to create a new case record type and page layout so that I can track and manage the long lists of requests that I receive for my Salesforce org - (presently I'm a solo admin). I know that people have done this, but I was hoping for an example, or perhaps some best practices to keep in mind - perhaps some good links that show how anyone has previously set up the page layout?
We don't use our cases object for anything at the moment, but I'll still be making a new Internal Support record type.

Comment: Leslie - welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! Stack Exchange really focuses on specific questions that have an answer that can be identified as "correct." Discussion or best practices questions don't fit the format very well.

Comment: If you can rephrase your question to be more specific, I bet you'll get some good answers. All that said, I would say that you want to make it as easy as possible for your users to make a bug report or feature request. Guide them towards providing adequate detail, eg with questions as default values in text areas, but don't bog them down with lots of categorizations and picklists.

Comment: Since you have a new record type, I hope you'll try to take advantage of Publisher/Object  Actions to pre-fill as much as possible for your users. Minimalist approaches are always good for readability; particularly the use of spacing to separate related information into useful blocks of information. Put what's most important to your users near the top of the page which is where they will tend to look first. Organize it similar to other pages so it won't appear foreign to them, either that or rearrange the others to match. Inconsistency is confusing to users.